# how to add user's information in mongoose database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms, jade4j

i have a registration form in .jade format

```
form(method='post', action='/users/register', enctype='multipart/form-data')
      .form-group
          label Name
          input.form-control(name='name', type='text', placeholder='Enter Name' required)
      .form-group
          label Email
          input.form-control(name='email', type='email', placeholder='Enter Email' required)
      .form-group
          label Username
          input.form-control(name='username', type='text', placeholder='Usernamee' required)
      .form-group
          label Password
          input.form-control(name='password', type='password', placeholder='Enter Password' required)
      .form-group
          label Password
          input.form-control(name='password2', type='password', placeholder='Confirm Password' required)
      .form-group
          label Profile Image
          input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
      input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', values='Register')
```

and this is how i'm creating a new user and trying to add them to the database but the data is not being added into the database.  The problem is it's not taking values from the form fields:
name, email username, password are all NULL 
I don't understand why as it's supposed to take all values

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
var newUser = new User({
          name: req.body.name, 
          email: req.body.email,
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password,
          profileImage: profileImageName
      });
}
```

Comment: may be you have provided `action='/users/register'` and in router you have `/register`, do you have `users/` as a prefix before coming to this router.post ??

Comment: no i dont have users/ as a prefix, if i add users/ ..it gives an error

Comment: Ok, then change `action='/register'` in your jade code it will work

Comment: if i remove users from action it gives an error

Comment: ok then may be you have `/users` already before coming to this route .
have you used `app.use(express.bodyParser());` middle-ware in the file where you have initialized the app ?

Comment: nope, should I?

Comment: yes, body-parser extract the entire body portion of an incoming request stream and exposes it on req.body.
Install body-parser using NPM as .

`npm install body-parser --save`
and then include it `app.use(express.bodyParser());`

Comment: its giving an error "Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware."

Comment: ok for newer version of express you need to use it like below  :-

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: nope, it doesnt help ..can you share your apple id so i can sare my screen with you

Comment: Try adding this `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` and `app.use(express.json());`. Not `bodyParser`

Comment: nope, it doesn't help

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with `multipart/form-data`. `body-parser` does not handle multipart bodies. Try using a middleware like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). There are several other modules suggested in their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme) for handling multipart bodies.

Answer (score 0):

You need a body parsing middleware to parse incoming request bodies.

Express has a [built-in middleware function](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded)(which is based on the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme) module) to parse urlencoded bodies since v4.16.0 onwards. But this built-in parser does not handle multipart bodies.

Since you're trying to handle a `multipart/form-data`, you may need a middleware like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme).